# How can I get my Windows drive to show in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: mount, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It works fine but it does not show any of the Windows partitions neither is it showing any pen drive that i'm trying to insert. It was also not showing any external hard disk.

**Edit**

When I'm mounting the drives by mount command, it gets mounted.
The problem seems to be with auto mount.

I also tried typing `dconf-editor` in terminal and then see the auto mount option under `org.gnome.desktop.media-handler`. It was set. So what is the problem now?

Comment: What commands have you tried/ Where are you looking? Does `lsusb` list your pendrive and external hardrive?

Comment: I don't know much about mounting and unmounting but it is showing my pendrive on doing lsusb. Can I see the same for windows partitions as well using some other command.

Comment: When you open Nautilus do you see anything drives on the side that say '500gb Filesystem' (if you Windows partition is 500gb). Or anything similar, maybe the size of your pendrive. Putting up a screenshot of Nautilus would help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputations to post an image. :(

Comment: It does not show anything like "500 GB filesystem" or similar.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? This will show all hard drives/USB sticks connected along with their partitions. We can try mounting them manually. Also, if you want to post an image, upload it to http://imgur.com/ and give us the link of the image.

Comment: Whops, you mentioned in the question that you can mount them. Type `gnome-disks` in the terminal. Highlight your hard disk partitions or USB pen drive. Click on the "gears" icon underneath the "Volumes" section, then Edit Mount Options (http://i.imgur.com/7IHgivH.png). What does it show? Try setting "Auto Mount Options" to ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removable drives, go to *settings manager* and select *Removable Drives and Media*. There you can select to mount these devices when hot-plugged. With regards to your other OS partitions, they can be listed in `/etc/fstab`, so that they will be **automounted** at boot time.